# PROC SQL: Warning variable already exists on multiple dataset join

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have this data check integrity code for an oncology study I'm working on. This is ostensibly to confirm TU,TR and RS are consistent.

```
 proc sql ;
 create table tu_tr_rs as 
 select tu.*,tr.*,rs.*
 from trans.tu  as tu
 left join trans.tr as tr on tu.usubjid=tr.usubjid and tu.TULNKID
 =tr.TRLNKID and tu.tudtc=tr.trdtc
 left join trans.rs as rs on tr.usubjid=rs.usubjid and tr.trdtc=
 rs.rsdtc
 ;
 quit;
```

However, when I run this code I get the warning

"Variable XXXX already exists on file WORK.TU_TR_RS."

When I add the feedback option to PROC SQL to get a more granular look I get this

[image]

So I know if it's one variable that brings this warning up you can use a rename/DROP combination to work around it but for this case is it just the case that I have to explicitly state the variables for each dataset in the select statement or is there something fundamentally wrong with the code?

Comment: What is your question exactly?  What is the goal of joining these datasets?  Are you trying to add variables to TU?  Then do not use TR.* or RS.*, only list the variables from TR and RS that you want to add.  Assign them new names if there is already a variable with that name in TU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to select columns with the same name from 2 (or more) data sets, you simply need to select them explicitly and give them distinct names.  Something like this:

```
create table tu_tr_rs as 
 select
    tu.ColA as tu_ColA
    ,tu.ColB as tu_ColB
    /* etc */
    ,tr.ColA as tr_ColA
    ,tr.ColB as tr_ColB
    /* etc */
    ,rs.ColA as rs_ColA
    ,rs.ColB as rs_ColB
    /* etc */
 from trans.tu  as tu
/* etc */
```